# Calling controller method from a script

Tags: ajax, spring, scripting

I need to call Spring controller method from script. Script call is on button onClick="save()". I have tried a script:

```
 function save() {
 alert("start")
 $.ajax({
 type: 'GET',
 url: '/myforms',

success: function() {
  alert("success");

}
```

And the method is:

```
@RequestMapping( method = RequestMethod.GET, params="db_save", value="myforms.html")
public String db_save(Model model,@ModelAttribute("myObject") MyObject myObject,    HttpServletRequest request) {


        // database updates and other stuff here


      return "myforms";
```

I am missing something, but what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JQuery, you use `/myforms`, but the controller maps to `myforms.html`. Change one or the other.

Comment: One problem remaining: I'm not able to keep the modelattribute object when running the method. It's null

Comment: @mjgirl OK, but you're not sending anything in the first place. perhaps you should use [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) together with [$(form).serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) instead?